# Does accessing a property on an NSManagedObject from a background thread make the context cross that thread?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I need to use a property on my NSManagedObjectContext as a parameter in a method that runs in the background.  After this method is called I then have problems from that point forward with that context even though all I did was get a property value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385):

> Any time you manipulate or access managed objects, you use the associated managed object context. Core Data does not present a situation where reads are “safe” but
>   changes are “dangerous”—every operation is “dangerous” because every
>   operation has cache coherency effects and can trigger faulting.

I've been working with Core Data in multi-threaded apps for some time (also in pre-iOS 5 era, without parent contexts etc.). I suspect it does some threading voodoo (locks and stuff) under the hood. If you want to be 100% safe, in a background thread you can't call any method on a `NSManagedObject` if its `NSManagedObjectContext` has not been created on the same thread. Otherwise, Undefined Behavior may happen (I got some deadlocks, for example).

Comment: so how then to a pass a property from an NSManagedObject context that was fetched in a context on the main thread?

Comment: When you use Core Data with queue-based concurrency type, you can use performBlockAndWait: on main thread's NSManagedObjectContext and read the property inside the block (the read operation will be performed on the main thread). Store the value in a `__block` local variable and then use that variable outside the block, in a background thread. If you use thread confinement concurrency type - you can safely pass `NSManagedObjectID` between threads. See this blog post for more details: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: gotcha, this code goes back to iOS 4.3 so no concurrency types are set on any contexts - looks like I have a lot to update - thanks